# Excel - i can only seem to "highlight" non-duplicate/non-unique values

Tags: excel

I have some data.

I would like to find the "unique" values in the data. That is, not any data that was duplicated.

To be clear:

```
A
B
C
A
B
```

I want

```
C
```

I do not particularly care if this makes a new column of modifies the existing column. I do not, however, want to get `C` highlighted - my data sets are v. large and i really don't want to be scrolling along finding hyper-color yellow entries.

*(I have a sneaking suspiscion this has been asked before, but given the dual connotations of "unique", it is kind of hard to search for it here)*

Comment: Why do you not want to have it highlighted? You can always filter on highlighted cells and copy/paste to another worksheet/book. And I've had data at 1M+ (close to excel's limit) filtering and copy/pasting data like that :)

Comment: yeah, guess that's what i'm going to have to do... wish Excel made that stuff easy for us though. I cannot imagine it would be any more than trivial to implement on their end.

Comment: That's true. Might be helpful to note that GoogleSpreadsheets does have the function `=UNIQUE()`, and can return the list of cells that are unique to a column!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional Formatting and Filtering is much the simplest, but if you really want a formula to obtain the unique values in a different column:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$5:$A$15,A5)=1,A5,"")
```

This assumes the original data is in A5:A15, and this formula is entered into another column and copied down the same number of rows. You'll end up with a load of blank cells though. You'll need to copy/paste-special values, then sort in descending order (or filter) this list so that the blanks are at the bottom and can be deleted.

Actually, slightly better would be:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$5:$A$15,A5)=1,A5,"zzz")
```

because, after copy/paste-special values, you can sort in ascending order and you can *see* the values (at the bottom) that you need to delete.

Answer (score 3):

Its a standard option of conditional formatting

[image: http://www.ablebits.com/_img-blog/excel-duplicates-conditional-formatting/unique-duplicate-values.png]

Duplicate is the default, But the box allows unique too

That menu is accessed from home tab > conditional formatting > new rule

be sure to set a format for the cell then